# why i failed to login coursera using requests library?

Tags: python, redirect, https, python-requests, coursera-api

the code i use is as follows:

```
import requests

url='https://accounts.coursera.org/api/v1/login'
s=requests.session()
r0=s.get('https://www.coursera.org/')
print r0.cookies.keys()
print 'get homepage'
payload={'email': 'use_your_email', 'password': 'xxx_use_your_password', 'webrequest':'true'}
r= s.post(url, data=payload)
```

The error message i get is **Invalid CSRF Token**, but in fact there is no data in r0.cookie.keys(), **anybody knows if there is something wrong in my code?** if yes, how to modify it? any clues? thank you:)

```
In [31]: r
Out[31]: <Response [400]>

In [32]: r.text
Out[32]: u'Invalid CSRF Token'
```

**some details**: the traffic is happened on https protocol, and it seems some redirection happens, don't know why redirection is needed? maybe it has something to do with security issues.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add a header "x-csrf-token" with a valid token